What player-facing options are there to allow a rogue to sneak attack off-turn?
Some abilities allow one of your allies to make an attack on your turn, such as Voice of Authority (Order Cleric) and Commander's Strike (Battlemaster Fighter). Since the Rogue's Sneak Feature is once per turn, not once per round, these features allow for extra sneak attacks. I'd like a list of features that would allow an allied rogue to make an attack outside their turn (without burning their action) from the following sources:

Player's Handbook
Xanathar's Guide to Everything
Tasha's Cauldron of Everything

I'm specifically looking for features that a player could choose to take on a level-up, not magic items that would have to be found.

Since all attacks off turn use your reaction, and you only get 1 per round, your question boils down to align with this one

Does this answer your question? How can I get more triggers for reaction attacks?

That answer is missing the Brace maneuver from the Battle Master for some reason, which I'd consider a better option that Riposte, specially if paired with the Swashbuckler as you can just walk away from the enemy and force them to re-engage

Commander's Strike and Voice of Authority are unique and costly, but Haste isn't
Aside from the abilities you mentioned, the Haste spell can give the rogue in your party an attack on their turn without using that turn's action.  They can then use the 'Ready' action, declaring that they will attack their target when anyone they can see takes an action or moves, then end their turn.  This will consume their reaction when activated, but it will allow them to Sneak Attack twice.
These sorts of interactions are pretty meta-gamey, but RAW it works.  Voice of Authority comes up rarely because it has to be a leveled spell cast on the rogue, which is usually not optimal.  Commander's Strike is easier to build around, but it consumes one of the fighter's attacks, their superiority die, and their bonus action, as well as the rogue's reaction, and if the fighter is running something like Crossbow Expert or Polearm Master they may not want to pay the cost.
Finally, the answer in the comments provides features that the rogue can take to maximize the uses for their reaction.

Our party doesn't even have a cleric. However, my wizard just reached 6th level, and I haven't picked my new spells. Thanks to this, I will definitely take haste. Thank you for pointing out this combo!
